# How to organize async response in RxJS (or FRP more generically)

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, reactivex, frp

Let's say we have a `source$` observable, which is usually user interaction. And we want to perform an async operation on each firing of `source$` and "map" the async result to an output observable, say `result$`.

### mergeMap

The naivest implementation is

```js
result$ = source$.pipe(
  mergeMap((s) => someAsyncOperation(s))
)
```

However, it is possible for a previous response to override most recent response because `someAsyncOperation` may spend different amount of time for each round.

```
source: -----1-----2------->
result1:     -----------|
result2:           --|
result: -------------2--1-->
```

The last value on `result$` observable is `1`, which is incorrect as we have already triggered the operation for `2` and the response `2` has already arrived.

### switchMap

We can replace `mergeMap` with `switchMap` and the graph would be:

```
source: -----1-----2------->
result1:     -----------|
result2:           --|
result: -------------2----->
```

For typical use cases like search suggestion, `switchMap` is desirable since the `response-1` is most likely to be valueless once `action-2` is fired.

### Problem

But for some other cases, responses for previous actions may still be valid. For example, for a periodic polling scenario, responses are valuable as long as their chronical order is perserved.

```
source: -----1-----2----3------->
result1:     --------|
result2:           -----------|
result3:                ----|
mergeMap: -----------1------3-2->
switchMap:------------------3--->

expected: -----------1------3--->
```

It's obvious that `response-1` and `response-3` are both desirable as they arrive in chronical order (while `response-2` is invalid because it arrives after `response-3`).

The problem with `mergeMap` is that it cannot omit the invalid `response-2`.
While `switchMap` is also suboptimal because it omits a desirable value `response-1` as the second observable has already started when `response-1` arrives. The problem of `switchMap` worsens when the average RTT is larger than the polling interval.

```
source: -----1----2----3----4----5----->
result1:     --------|
result2:          --------|
result3:               --|
result4:                    -------|
result5:                         ----|
switchMap:---------------3------------->
expected: -----------1---3---------4-5->
```

*You can see `switchMap` generates far less outputs than the ideal one*

### Question

How should I get the expected output observable in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach an "emission index" to each response and use that to filter out older emissions.

```js
const result$ = source$.pipe(
  mergeMap((s, index) => someAsyncOperation(s).pipe(
    map(response => ({ response, index }))
  )),
  scan((prev, cur) => ({...cur, maxIndex: Math.max(prev.maxIndex, cur.index)}), INITIAL),
  filter(({index, maxIndex}) => index === maxIndex),
  map(({response}) => response),
);
```

Here we can use [`scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan) to keep track of the highest emitted index thus far, then use [`filter`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter) to prevent emissions from older requests.

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-74972058?devtoolsheight=75&file=index.ts) demo.

Comment: Hi @BizzyBob, thanks for the effective answer. I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to achieve this. Having an "emission index" feels itchy somehow.

Comment: What I'm looking for is, conceptually, a variant of "switchMap" where the "switch" happens when the first value comes on each higher order observables rather than when the higher order observables themselves are fired.

Comment: There may be a cleaner way, but I can’t think of one :-)

Comment: If the “switch” were to happen when the inner observable emits, you still don’t know if you should switch because you won’t know if the request was made later than the request for the previous emission. So, at the point the inner observable emits, we need a way to determine if it is from a newer request than the previously emitted value.

Comment: Maybe we could roll the code above into a custom operator `mergeNewer`?

Comment: I think I have managed to implement a `switchMap2` without any emission index.
It seems to achieve what is expected but the I haven't finalized it to cover error cases and validate the memory management.
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-74972058-bhq6hy?devtoolsheight=75&file=index.ts)

Comment: Why "switch" can eliminate the need for emission index is that the order is implicitly guaranteed by unsubscribing the previous subscriptions. In the offical `switchMap` operator, the unsubscription happens when the outer observable emits. While I changed it to happen when the inner observable emits